# If ||Av|| = ||A*v||, then AA*=A*A.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let V be a finite dimensional space over C, with a positive definite hermitian product. Let $ A: V->V$ be linear.

Show that if $ \forall v \in V, ||Av|| = ||A^*v|| $, then 
$ AA^*=A^*A $, Where A* is adjoint of A.

---

Pf: 
$ <Av,Av>=<A^*v,A^*v> $

$ <Av,Av>-<A^*v,A^*v>=0 $

$<(A-A^*)v,(A-A^*)v>=0$

By positive definite h. product, (A-A*)v = 0, so A = A*.
Then we can get AA = A*A = AA *.

Is there anything wrong with that proof?

---

Also, in serge lang's solutions manual, they say the following

$ <Av, Av>=<A^*v, A^*v> $

$ <A^*Av, v> = <AA^*v,v> $

$ <A^*Av-AA^*v,v> =0$. So A*A = AA *.

How did they get the second step, namely that $<Av,Av>=<A^*Av,v>$ from the assumption?

edit: A is linear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adjoint always has the property $\langle A u \mid v\rangle = \langle u \mid A^* v \rangle $.

Also your calculation is wrong because

\begin{align}
\langle (A-A^*)v \mid (A-A^*)v \rangle
&= \langle Av\mid (A-A^*)v \rangle - \langle A^*v\mid (A-A^*)v \rangle \\
&= \langle Av \mid Av \rangle - \langle Av\mid A^* v \rangle - \langle A^*v \mid Av\rangle + \langle A^*v \mid A^*v \rangle
\end{align}

which is in general not equal to $\langle Av \mid Av \rangle - \langle A^*v \mid A^*v \rangle$

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how you got from
$$\langle Av,Av\rangle-\langle A^*v,A^*v\rangle=0$$
to
$$\langle (A-A^*)v,(A-A^*)v\rangle.$$

In Lang's solution, he uses the definition of $A^*$, that is
$$\langle v,A^*u\rangle=\langle Av,u\rangle.$$

Comment: Doesn't that follow from properties of the scalar product and linearity of A?

Comment: So in the solns, he used the adjoint property, and let A=A*, used the fact that A**=A?

Comment: @skim I don't think it follows. For example, if $x^2-y^2=0$ (as real numbers), it doesn't follow that $(x-y)^2=0$.
Yes, he used the adjoint property and $A^{**}=A$.